# How can I blend in my SegmentedControl in a UITableView better?

Tags: user-interface, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

As you can see on the screenshot the segmented control is placed rather ugly this way.

I need it in that place, meaning below the section title and before the second cell for that section. How could I make this better?

[image]

Comment: @jonkroll: there you go, completely forgot to do it :p

Comment: I really like @jonkroll's idea. If you insist on using a UISegmentedControl, maybe make the cell a little larger and add a little margin at the top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two suggestions that would improve the appearance.  The first would be to increase the height of the table cell (just that particular table cell, not all of the cells in your table) so that the whitespace margin at the top and bottom of your segmented control is equal to the margin you currently have on the left and right of the control.

Another solution would be to move the selection of the value for this setting into a separate tableView controller that you drill down to.  So that cell would show the current value, but tapping the cell would take the user to a new view where the user could select to change the value.

Here is an example of this from the Instapaper app settings page that I think looks pretty clean.

[image]  [image]